JMeter Invalid URI Host Name
I had created a project using Jmeter and created thread group and one Http Request sampler.
I left the server name or ip empty and put the url in path section but when i generate report using this command

jmeter.sh -g Report.jtl -o report

Erros in the report:

Non HTTP response code:
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException/Non HTTP response
message: URI does not specify a valid host name:
http:/www.google.com.my

I specify the path using this value https://www.google.com.my

www.google.com.my is not a valid URI path, that should be the host/server

I cannot reproduce your issue with latest JMeter 5.6.3 so I think it's some form of a bug which has been fixed.
Here is the evidence: https://i.imgur.com/pMipzTu.gif
In general it's recommended to always use the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading, you can always get a stable version of JMeter from Downloads page.
